# Column of links in Ember Table

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-table

Lets say that I have a model with two attributes: `name` and `url`. If I want to build a column of links like this `<a href="url">name</a>` how can I do it? as far as I know, using `contentPath` or `getCellContent` only allow me to send one of those attributes.

I've been trying something like this:

> controller.js

```
Column.create({
  headerCellName: 'link',
  contentPath: 'url',
  tableCellView: TableCell.extend({
    templateName: 'link'
  })
})
```

> link.hbs

```
{{#link-to view.cellContent}} 
 ???
{{/link-to}}
```

But I'm stuck in the way of letting the template know those two fields. I'm very new to ember so sorry if this is a newbie question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. It seems that in the end, `getCellContent` allows to pass the complete model so I can access its attributes by `view.row.name` or `view.row.url` in the template.